# ¿Menu scroll animado no funciona en la versión 3.3.1 de jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Estoy actualizando mi sitio web en los cambios mas actuales guiandome en los cambios y reemplazando `$(function() {});` por `$(document).ready(function()` pero mi menú scroll no funciona la animación en la versión `3.3.1` de `jQuery` actualmente la animación o mi código funciona con la versión `2.1.3` `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js`

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent hard jump, the default behavior

    var target = $(this).attr("href"); // Set the target as variable

    // perform animated scrolling by getting top-position of target-element and set it as scroll target
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 600, function() {
      location.hash = target; //attach the hash (#jumptarget) to the pageurl
    });

    return false;
  });
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollDistance = $(window).scrollTop();

  // Show/hide menu on scroll
  //if (scrollDistance >= 850) {
  //  $('nav').fadeIn("fast");
  //} else {
  //  $('nav').fadeOut("fast");
  //}
 
  // Assign active class to nav links while scolling
  $('.page-section').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).position().top <= scrollDistance) {
      $('.navigation a.active').removeClass('active');
      $('.navigation a').eq(i).addClass('active');
    }
  });
}).scroll();
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: all .1s ease;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 64px;
}

.page-section {
  height: 480px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding: 3em;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #43cea2 10%, #185a9d 90%);
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
}
.navigation__link {
  display: block;
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.navigation__link:hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.navigation__link.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<nav class="navigation" id="mainNav">
   <a class="navigation__link" href="#aaa">Section 1</a>
   <a class="navigation__link" href="#bbb">Section 2</a>
   <a class="navigation__link" href="#ccc">Section 3</a>
   <a class="navigation__link" href="#ddd">Section 4</a>
    <a class="navigation__link" href="#eee">Section 5</a>
    <a class="navigation__link" href="#fff">Section 6</a>
    <a class="navigation__link" href="#7">Section 7</a>
</nav>

<div class="page-section hero" id="1">
   <h1>Smooth scroll, fixed jump menu with active class</h1>
</div>
<div class="page-section" id="aaa">
   <h1>Section Two</h1>
</div>
<div class="page-section" id="bbb">
   <h1>Section Three</h1>
</div>
<div class="page-section" id="ccc">
   <h1>Section Four</h1>
</div>
<div class="page-section" id="ddd">
   <h1>Section Five</h1>
</div>
<div class="page-section" id="eee">
   <h1>Section Six</h1>
</div>
<div class="page-section" id="fff">
   <h1>Section Seven</h1>
</div>
```

¿Qué cambios debo considerar, un poco confuso normalmente se utilizar cosas muy sencillas y pequeñas sobre jQuery no profundalizo mucho su uso.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi tu problema y lo que consegui fue que esta mal declarado el selector de esta linea (**No es problema de la version de JQuery**):

```
$('a[href*=#]').bind('click', function(e) {
```

La he cambiado por esta otra:

```
$("[href^='#']").bind('click', function(e) {
```

En cuanto a expresiones para declarar **selectores + atributos + valores** aqui te adjunto el link de una pagina que explica como hacerlo;

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Ahora ejecutando que esta muy bonito el diseño, veo que al seleccionar un item del menu se desplaza un bloque mas del correspondiente, es decir, pulso el item Section 2 y muestra el Section Three, parece que el codigo esta hecho para hacer ese comportamiento.

Tambien puedes Ayudarte: **Usando en el Navegador la tecla F12** puedes ver la ejecucion del codigo y de esta forma puedes analizar reportes del funcionamiento y futuras fallas en la pagina.

Comment: Gracias funciona perfectamente :)